# How to reference the parent element in the DOM in an ASPX page?

Tags: html, asp.net, dom

Here's my page snippet:

```
...
<asp:Content ID="Main" ContentPlaceHolderID="PlaceHolderMain" runat="server">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <asp:TextBox MaxLength="255" ID="myTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</asp:Content>
...
```

And here's the page code-behind piece:

```
...
Control parent = this.myTextBox.Parent; //this is acutally asp:Content control
string parentID = parent.ID; //this is PlaceHolderMain
...
```

What I need is to reference the `<td>` element (because I want to change it's `Visibility` property). How can I achieve this? Where did I go so horribly wrong? :)

Comment: You didn't go wrong. You just didn't go :-). See my answer

Comment: can we do it without the server tag ? because i can't modify the grids of entire application. I need to get last textbox to a grid and apply some JS code to it but sometimes grid have last textbox hidden by css applied on the <td> .  see i need to check if it's hidden or not then apply JS to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add attribute runat to `<td>` tag as other users suggested.

```
<td id="mytd" runat="server">
   <asp:TextBox MaxLength="255" ID="myTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
```

Then in c# side (page back)

add this header file

```
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
protected void Button_click(object sender,EventArgs e)
{
  mytd.Attributes.Add("style","visibility:none");
}
```

Comment: Thanks Subin Jacob! Since all the answers are correct, I decided to endorse your answer because you have the least amount of points :)

Answer (score 1):

`td` needs to be ran server side for it to be accessed and classed as a parent element.

```
<td id="td" runat="server">
   <asp:TextBox MaxLength="255" ID="myTextBox" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

ASPX Code behind really only knows about the ASP controls (i.e. the ones with the asp: prefix in the tags) the td is just plain old html. In order for the code behind to interacte with it, you will need to add a runat="server" on the tag

Answer (score 0):

The table over here is an html table not an ASP.NET server control. So you can't access it in the code behind.

Use this in case :

```
<asp:Table ID="Table1" runat="server">
            <asp:TableRow ID="TableRow1" runat="server" ForeColor="Teal">
                <asp:TableCell>
                    <asp:TextBox MaxLength="255" ID="myTextBox" runat="server"> 
                    </asp:TextBox>
                </asp:TableCell>
            </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
```